# Git Lab CI: How to restart(relaunch) test after failure(fail)?

Tags: selenium, pytest, gitlab-ci

How to restart(relaunch) test after failure(fail)?

I've test ci_events_page.py  (pytest-selenium test)

yml settings(.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
ci_events_page.py:
 stage: test
 type: test
 script:
 - xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1080x24" pytest --driver Chrome ci/ci_events_page.py -v
```

test is ok! But when test failed - job failed too...I want to restart few times test when it's failing. Please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [retry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#retry) option. This will retry the job x times.

Retry job 2 times:

> ..retry value has to be a positive integer, equal or larger than 0, but lower or equal to 2 (two retries maximum, three runs in total).

```
ci_events_page.py:
 stage: test
 type: test
 retry: 2
 script:
 - xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1080x24" pytest --driver Chrome ci/ci_events_page.py -v
```

Comment: Done, added to answer

Comment: FAILED((( Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/96d79fb4dad2c1b40d51a8a70165d443

Comment: Please change to 2.

Comment: two retries maximum <<< circus (